# How to allow user to edit post in wordpress

Tags: user-roles

I want to allow users to edit the posts without giving the admin access. I have a Basic Authentication plugin which stopping them to access it. But when i deactivate it they're able to edit the posts with contributor role access.

Now, My requirement is Basic Authentication plugin should be active and the users should able to edit the posts.

Can someone help me with this.

Thanks

Comment: Why not give them a custom role that allows them to edit posts and their user info, but nothing else?

Comment: I have used capability and given the contributor and edit access to the role. but still i am having the issue

Comment: You might need to check with the Basic Authentication plugin developer. I meant, give them regular accounts and a custom role that restricts what they can access in the admin area, and then potentially get rid of the authentication plugin that's giving you trouble.

Comment: We are using the basic authentication for rest API calling for Micro services if i disable it that service not work.

Answer (score 1):

It would seem like the Basic Authentication Plugin is modifying the `contributor` user role, removing their `edit_posts` capability. As you need this plugin activated, I see a couple of options

## Make a new user role with edit-post capabilities

Create a new role that has only the capabilities you need it to have. That way you avoid messing with the permissions of an existing role. Add this piece of code to your plugin main file (changing function names, capabilities and role data as you seem fit).

```
function add_new_special_rol(){
    $role = add_role( 'special_role_slug', 'Special Role Name', array(//Capabilities array
       'edit_posts'     => true, // True allows that capability
       'switch_themes'  => false, // False restricts that capability
    ));
}

function remove_special_rol(){
    $role = remove_role('special_role_slug');
}

register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'add_new_special_rol' );
register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'remove_special_rol' );
```

Keep in mind that the `add_role` and `remove_role` functions modify the database, so they should be **used only when deactivating or activating a plugin/theme**, thats why we hook the functions with `register_activation_hook` and `register_deactivation_hook`.

**You can see all capabilities available here**
https://wordpress.org/support/article/roles-and-capabilities/#switch_themes

## Edit the Contributor role capabilites

You can override whatever value the `edit_posts` capability has for the `contributor` role.

```
function modify_contributor_role_capabilities($wp_roles){
    //We get the contributor role object
    $contributor_role = $wp_roles->get_role('contributor');
    if($contributor_role)
        //then we make them be able to edit posts modifying their capabilities array
        $contributor_role->capabilities['edit_posts'] = true;
};
//Hook the function to the 'wp_roles_init' hook, that gives us access to the WP_Roles instance
//high priority just in case
add_action( 'wp_roles_init', 'modify_contributor_role_capabilities', 999 );
```

In this case we are be modifying the `contributor` role directly, no database modifications. This is posible through the `wp_roles_init` action hook, which **can only be used in a plugin**.

Comment: Thanks Raba for your inputs.